# Finding three points on a plan that do not lie on the same straight line.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an equation $2x+3y+4z=5$ that describes a plane $P$ in three dimensions and I'm looking for three points on my plan that do not lie on the same straight line.

*I don't get what the question refers to when it asks for 3 points that do not lie on the same straight line.*
This is what I have in mind so far: I think since a plane is made of two points that are not parallel with each other, so those provide my first 2 points.

Any suggestions on how I should go about to find these points is appreciated.

Comment: Because the origin is not in this plane (how do I know that?), you can easily find three linearly independent points by setting two variables to $0$ and finding the third.  So $(0,0,\frac 54)$, $(0,\frac 53,0)$ and $(\frac 52,0,0)$ are all points on the plane, but there's no line that goes through all three of them.

Comment: Brilliant! You made life a whole lot easier Bye_World.

Comment: No problem. :-)